# SQL Agent Job: Seeking Process flow advice on managing steps

Tags: sql-server-agent, process

Fellow DBAs,
I need some practical advice on how to solve a job timing issue on different servers. I have a SQL Agent job that currently has steps 1-10.  Step #8 has a dependency on a SQL Agent job on another box completing successfully. What is the best approach in checking to see what state this job is in?  Do I place Step #8-10 as a separate job that launches from the original job, after adding a step to the original job that queries the agent job status on the other box? If successfully completed--launches the new job? How would you suggest I manage situations where the job that is the dependency is still running? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: check `sysjobhistory` to make sure it has completed, if not, WAITFOR how ever long you want and check again?

Comment: An option _might_ be to split 8-10 into a separate job.  Then add a step on the remote server to use a linked server (need proper authority on original server to start a job) pointing back to the original server and run `sp_start_job` when the remote server process completes.  You may not be willing to open this up for security reasons.